# content:url in CSS for multiple images

Tags: css, image, mobile, responsive

I asked a similar question before and thought it had been solved but actually it wasn't fully solved. This time, I'm going to use the specific example I'm working on to see if it's a problem with this particular code.

I have in CSS for desktop:

```
div.image {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/masterpiece-
transformers.jpg);
}

div.imagea1 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/news.jpg);
}​

div.imagea2 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/releases.jpg);
}​

div.imagea3 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/design-team-interview-archives.jpg);
}​

div.imagea4 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/reviews.jpg);
}​
```

then in CSS for mobile:

```
div.image {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/masterpiece-
transformers.jpg);
width:100%;
}​

div.imagea1 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/news.jpg);
width:25%;
}​

div.imagea2 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/releases.jpg);
width:25%;
}​

div.imagea3 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/design-team-interview-
archives.jpg);
width:25%;
}​

div.imagea4 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/reviews.jpg);
width:25%;
}​
```

and then in HTML:

```
<div class="containertop">

<div class="image">

</div>

</div>

<div class="breadcrumb">

<div class="imagea1">

</div>

<div class="imagea2">

</div>

<div class="imagea3">

</div>

<div class="imagea4">

</div>

</div>
```

I have a few problems with this. For some reason, on desktop only the first 2 images display (image and imagea1). On mobile, after I set the width of the first image to 100%, that started displaying. However, as I was tinkering around with the code to try and get this working, something went wrong and currently no images are displaying on mobile. It had seemed as if setting the width to 100% was allowing the image to display correctly on mobile (native image width is 900 pixels, I'll actually be altering that to 1024 but I can't imagine that's anything to do with anything).

I'm doing the images in this way rather than in a more conventional way as it had seemed it would allow me to specify percentage widths for images which is useful for getting everything the right size on mobile.

I may be missing something really obvious but I've looked over the code again and again and can't understand why imagea1 displays on desktop and then imagea2 doesn't considering they seem to be coded in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific issues you had, but this is what I noticed when I tested your code out.

The images didn't appear at all, but after a bit of trial and error, it magically did.

For my test, the problem had to do with the `div`s. `div`s are block elements, and take up the full width of the browser's resolution.

On certain browsers, trying to have an image be stretched as large as the `viewport` would make it crash and not  render at all. For images it's really important to have a proper size, container and properties for it.

In my example below, I set a fixed width for them (`100%` was cancer for me), and a fixed height (`200px` for example).

Hope I helped!

```css
.image {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/masterpiece-
transformers.jpg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.imagea1 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/news.jpg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.imagea2 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/releases.jpg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.imagea3 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/design-team-interview-archives.jpg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.imagea4 {
content:url(http://www.masterpiecetransformers.com/images/reviews.jpg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containertop">

<div class="image">
</div>

</div>

<div class="imagea1">

</div>

<div class="imagea2">

</div>

<div class="imagea3">

</div>

<div class="imagea4">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've experimented with widths and heights and it hasn't fixed the issue for me. When I run your code snippet it does display the last 4 images for me, but I've tried specifically isolating the images CSS codes and running a test just on those (to protect against possible errors elsewhere in my code that may affect things) and it still only shows 'image' and 'imagea1' in the browser...

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle of the isolated code you've tried and post the link here please?

Comment: Are you using a special keyboard or do you have text replacement thingamabooboos going on?

Comment: for some reason it shows small red boxes with dots in after the last 4 closing brackets...those don't seem to correspond to anything in my code though. I just checked, if I remove those it displays correctly all 5 images...but they don't seem to correspond to any character in my CSS file! very confused...

Comment: What OS are you on, and what text editor are you using?

Comment: I assume you just noticed the same thing as me...I'm not aware of having any special keyboard or text replacement thingamabooboo...

Comment: hmmm, i've used only macs my whole life so i wouldn't know how to help you on that. Chances are, there's an option in the settings that can enable or disable that. Some text editors I know on mac do that. Basically it adds a weird character at the end of the last line of the block, to basically just signify the _end_ of it. Have a poke around and see what you can find, and maybe google or ask someone you might know about it. Or, try a different editor! :)

Comment: I've googled it but i haven't found anything useful on windows

Comment: for example there's [this](https://superuser.com/a/543833) for MS Word, and [this](https://superuser.com/a/409921) for Notepad++. I assume you're using Notepad++. I think that's the solution

Comment: I think I've solved it, I'm going to try answering my own question. Thanks for your help, I would never have seen it without jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

OK, answering my own question here as I've managed to figure it out with help from Mark, below.

I was using vanilla Notepad and the problem seemed to be I had saved the styles.css file using character encoding ANSI. ANSI was specifically causing the closing brackets '}' to format incorrectly. I googled and it is recommended in nearly all cases to use UTF-8. So you want to declare your stylesheet as UTF-8 in the head section of your HTML:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css; charset=utf-8"/>
```

I had done this but was then using ANSI so already a problem! Then it's advised to declare the stylesheet as UTF-8 in the first line of the stylesheet, here's the code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

However with vanilla Notepad you're also going to want to make sure you change the encoding to UTF-8 when you first 'Save As' the file, there's a box to the left of the 'Save' button...

One final thing, be warned if you try copying an ANSI stylesheet's content and subsequently saving it as UTF-8, you're still going to want to delete the ending brackets '}' and replacing them with fresh ending brackets as some of the formatting carries over invisibly.